# Can a virtual machine be split across multiple drives?

Tags: parallels

I am considering the option to move my existing Windows 7 image to run inside Parallels on my new Mac. It appears this is possible and not that unusual.

But, I am speccing the new Mac to have an SSD and fixed disk. I want the W7 image to run fast but at 200Gb, I don't want to use all my SSD on a single VM.

Is it possible to do the same thing with VMs, as regular PCs, where you put OS/applications on SSD and data files on a slower larger drive? Modern VMs are very clever and so I wondered if this was possible - maybe even move the data files into a separate drive somehow.

Answer (score 2):

While I have never used parallels, every other VM software I have seen allow you to create multiple "virtual drives" and each one can be represented by a separate file.

You then can put your small fast "virtual C:" file on your SSD and put your slow big "virtual D:" on a separate large spinning disk drive.

EDIT: [Here is a link to the parallels documentation](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/22185.htm) on how to add an additional virtual drive to the VM.

Comment: Thanks. Would it commonly be possible to do this _after_ creating the VM?

Comment: @John I to have little experience with Parrellels, but YES it is common to be able to add more virtual drives to an existing machine if the virtual machine is powered off first.

Comment: @John yes, as Robin said, all you need to do is first power down the VM and you should be able to add a new hard drive image to the VM. When you next turn on the VM it will act just as if you plugged an additional new hard drive to a real computer.